# How to display a multi-lined list nicely?

Tags: align

I want to maintain readability of each element by using alignment  point. At the same time I also don't want to make any further confusion as shown in the following figure in which the closing curly brace is not properly placed.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\[A =\{
    \begin{aligned}[t]
         &R_1R_1,R_1R_2,R_1P_1,R_1P_2,R_1P_3,\\
         &R_2R_1,R_2R_2,R_2P_1,R_2P_2,R_2P_3
    \end{aligned}
\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

How to move the closing curly brace to the proper place as shown in red? Any other suggestion is always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use the `\{...\}` environment inside the aligned environment

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt

    \[\begin{aligned}[t]
         A=\{&R_1R_1,R_1R_2,R_1P_1,R_1P_2,R_1P_3,\\
         &R_2R_1,R_2R_2,R_2P_1,R_2P_2,R_2P_3\}
    \end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: I   will use `split` instead of `aligned`.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity That's indeed a good suggestion, however, I wanted to stick with the OP's environment (as I didn't know the premise at which the OP uses the `aligned` environment).

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I didn't notice you were the OP ;) (extremely sorry for the 3rd person-ish comment)

Comment: :-):-):-):-):-)

Answer (score 4):

Here are two suggestions, one a `multlined` the other a large brace:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  A =
    \begin{multlined}[t]
         \{R_1R_1,R_1R_2,R_1P_1,R_1P_2,R_1P_3,\\
         R_2R_1,R_2R_2,R_2P_1,R_2P_2,R_2P_3\}
    \end{multlined}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  A =\biggl\{
    \begin{aligned}
         &R_1R_1,R_1R_2,R_1P_1,R_1P_2,R_1P_3,\\
         &R_2R_1,R_2R_2,R_2P_1,R_2P_2,R_2P_3
    \end{aligned}
\biggr\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by `Raaja`'s answer.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\[
\begin{split}
        A =\{ &R_1R_1,R_1R_2,R_1P_1,R_1P_2,R_1P_3,\\
                    &R_2R_1,R_2R_2,R_2P_1,R_2P_2,R_2P_3\}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}` is added because `varwidth` does not take any effect if `split` is used.